# zen load balancer virtual IP is masking origin SMTP IP which is leading to false spam in Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, load-balancing, zen

We have two exchange servers internally which are being served by Zen Load Balancer on 10.101.1.105 / 106.

When mail arrives, half of it gets blocked because of failed SPF checks.

The headers in the email:

```
Received: from EUR01-VE1-obe.outbound.protection.outlook.com (10.101.1.105) by
EXCH02.prfm.co.uk (10.101.7.102) with Microsoft SMTP Server id
15.0.1210.3 via Frontend Transport; Wed, 4 Jan 2017 09:20:48 +0000
```

The SPF in the headers

```
authentication-results: spf=none (sender IP is )
 smtp.mailfrom=madeup@madeup.madeup;
```

Sender IP is blank, I haven't removed that for security.

When I check the MX record for madeup.madeup, I get the SPF record

```
v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all
```

And the MX record

```
madeup-madeup.mail.protection.outlook.com
```

Is there a way to get ZLB to preserve the original IP address so it doesn't get blocked by SPF?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make Exchange aware of the internal SMTP Servers (your loadbalancer via):

```
Set-TransportConfig -InternalSMTPServers IP
```

or for multiple IPs:

```
Set-TransportConfig -InternalSMTPServers @{Add="ip address1","ip address2"...}
```

For more info's see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124151(v=exchg.160).aspx):

> The InternalSMTPServers parameter specifies a list of internal SMTP
>   server IP addresses or IP address ranges that should be ignored by
>   Sender ID and connection filtering